# How do I fix the action function of my form submission?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to redirect users to a pdf upon form submission however the link appears to be broken on initial arrival. The source code for the pdf appears first, however, if you refresh this page it displays correctly.

[pdf destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLS7P.jpg)

```html
<form name="landing" method="POST" data-netlify="true" action="img/newsletter.pdf">
  <div class="text-fields">
    <h3>Email address</h3>
    <input type="email" class="text-input email-input" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
  </div>
  <button class="btn-yellow" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try using GET method. Not sure

Comment: GET method works to enable the correct link, however, it then doesn't complete the form since I removed the POST method.

Comment: The form values will be sent in the URL query string when using a GET. POSTing to a PDF won't do anything with the data anyway. You probably want to POST to a separate endpoint, which redirects to the PDF on completion of processing the form.